# Can you see the other side of your own cards in uno flip?

Tags: uno, uno-flip

I have a question about uno flip. In uno flip can you see the other side of YOUR OWN cards.
Example:You are playing uno flip on the light side. You want to see YOUR OWN cards on the DARK side. Are you allowed to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can look at the other side of your own hand.

There's nothing in the [rules](https://www.ultraboardgames.com/uno/flip-game-rules.php), from what I see, that says you can't. So I definitely think you are allowed to do that.

From a practical standpoint, when you are dealt your hand, you'll see the dark side of your own hand while it's being dealt anyways.